# Accord de l'expression "en baisse"

Tags: accord, locutions

Je viens de demander à 6 correcteurs en ligne de vérifier cette phrase :

> Les prix sont en baisses.

Sur les 6, seulement un repère une faute et suggère de laisser baisse au singulier car « être en baisse » est une locution verbale.

Qui a raison ? et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 5):

***En baisse*** est une locution figée très courante et invariable comme le sont aussi : ***en hausse***, ***en équilibre***, ***en déséquilibre***, ***en avance***, ***en retard***, etc.

Answer (score 2):

L'unique correcteur à trouver une faute a raison ; on n'écrit pas « baisse » au pluriel dans ce contexte grammatical, quel que soit le nom (prix, niveaux, pommes de terre, investissements, etc.).

[image]

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baisse)) **baisse**
> **A.** − Action de baisser. Anton. hausse.
> **1.**  [En parlant du niveau de qqc., en partic. de l'eau] Action de diminuer de hauteur. **Être en baisse**. Être en train de diminuer

Comme le dictionnaire fournit une définition pour cette expression, elle doit être idiomatique. C'est la raison du singulier, du point de vue grammaire. Du point de vue logique, on peut dire que quoi que soient les choses dont on parle, on examine un état commun de ces choses, état qui est la baisse ; donc on utilise le singulier. Si l'on voulait parler de baisses variées on dirait par exemple « Les prix ont enregistrés des baisses plus ou moins importantes. ». C'est finalement le résultat d'un choix : avec le verbe « être » on ne considère que l'état commun et on utilise d'autres verbes pour traiter une idée de multiplicité.

Comment: *on peut dire que **quoi que soient** les choses dont on parle* → *on peut dire que **quelles que** soient les choses dont on parle*

Comment: @jlliagre On trouve l'exemple suivant : « Nous disposons donc d'une contrainte structurelle : quoi que soient les émotions, quelles que soient les expressions qu'elles prennent dans telle ou telle culture, de quelque façon qu'on les nomme dans tel ou tel lexique ». https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_couleur_des_pens%C3%A9es/NjbvDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22quoi+que+soient+les%22&pg=PA95&printsec=frontcover « Quelles » est correct, bien sûr, mais pourquoi pas ne pas utiliser « quoi », c'est à dire « quelle que soit la nature » ?

Comment: *Du point de vue **grammaire*** → *Du point de vue **grammatical***

Comment: *Les prix ont **enregistrés** des baisses* → *Les prix ont **enregistré** des baisses*

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quoi+que+soient%2Cquelles+que+soient%2Cquels+que+soient&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @jlliagre Merci pour l'accord du participe. En ce qui concerne « du point de vue … », il me semble avoir souvent entendu ça ; d'ailleurs j'en ai trouvé deux exemples (Du point de vue sécurité d'exploitation, l'avantage va actuellement au câble coaxial — Du point de vue pourcentage d'invalidité, la jurisprudence n'est pas ). Je ne comprends pas ce qui ne va pas ; c'est rejeté par qui ?

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle Je ne rejette pas totalement *Quoi que soient* mais la forme est trop rare pour ne pas faire sursauter et elle n'est pas recommandable dans une réponse qui va être lue par des apprenants. C'est la même chose pour *du point de vue grammaire* qui est un raccourci courant à l'oral mais qui risque d'être considéré comme incorrect ou au moins imparfait par un professeur de français.

Comment: @jlliagre Je suis plutôt d'accord. SSDD.